# Incorrect order of records in M-M relationship in hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, many-to-many

I have four records in bridge table in MySQL Database. Using @ManyToMany in hibernate, I get accurate order of employees but incorrect incorrect of projects. Following is the required material to figure out where I am doing the mistake.

[image: Original Data in MySQL Database]

[image: But I get following result at stdout]

This is the source.

```
        @Entity
        @Table(name="PROJECT")
        public class ProjectBean {

            @Id @GeneratedValue @Column(name="PROJECT_ID")
            private int projectId;
            @Column(name="TITLE")
            private String projectTitle;
            @ManyToMany(mappedBy="projects")
            private Collection<EmployeeBean> employees;
            public ProjectBean() {
                employees = new ArrayList<EmployeeBean>();
            }

            //getters & setters
}



@Entity
@Table(name="EMPLOYEE")
public class EmployeeBean {
    @Id @GeneratedValue @Column(name="EMPLOYEE_ID")
    private int employee_id;
    @Column(name="FIRST_NAME")
    private String firstName;
    @Column(name="LAST_NAME")
    private String lastName;
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name="EMPLOYEE_PROJECT",joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="EMPLOYEE_ID"),inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="PROJECT_ID"))
    private Collection<ProjectBean> projects;

    public EmployeeBean() {
         projects = new ArrayList<ProjectBean>();
    }
    //getters and setters goes here
}
```

and finally following is the Main Class where I am trying to traverse the list with the same order as we can see in the top most image.

```
        ArrayList<ProjectBean> projects = (ArrayList<ProjectBean>)session.createQuery("SELECT projects FROM EmployeeBean").list();
        ArrayList<EmployeeBean> employees = (ArrayList<EmployeeBean>)session.createQuery("SELECT employees FROM ProjectBean").list();
        System.out.println("EmpID\tPrjID");
        int i = 0;
        for (EmployeeBean employeeBean : employees) {
            System.out.print(employeeBean + "\t");
            ProjectBean projectBean = (ProjectBean) projects.get(i);
            i++;
            System.out.println(projectBean);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code really doesn't make sense. You iterate through employees, and for each employee at index `i` in the list of employees, you're printing the project at index `i` of the list of projects.

If you want to display all the projects of each employee, you need a single query, and two nested loops:

```
List<EmployeeBean> employees = session.createQuery("SELECT e FROM EmployeeBean e").list();
for (EmployeeBean employee : employees) {
    System.out.println(employee);
    for (Project project : employee.getProjects()) {
        System.out.println("\t" + employee);
    }
}
```

Also, note that I don't cast the list return by the query to ArrayList: this is completely useless, and works only because Hibernate happens to return an ArrayList. It could choose to return any other List instance, and your code would break. Program on interfaces.

Comment: Hi JB, In your HQL, the alias name `e` is not defined.